# Can Phoenix v4.4 utilize HBase namespaces?

Tags: permissions, namespaces, hbase, apache-phoenix

As we've been evaluating the use of Phoenix + HBase in HortonWorks 2.3, we came upon the conclusion that in the current bundled version of Phoenix, 4.4, that namespaces are not supported. The upstream JIRAs are confusing but it looks like Phoenix will not support namespaces + permissions until 4.7-4.8.

This is what we seen when enabling Phoenix on our system. The SYSTEM.* tables are Phoenix's. Ours are in the ns: namespace.

```
Version 1.1.2.2.3.6.0-3796, r2873b074585fce900c3f9592ae16fdd2d4d3a446, Thu Jun 23 16:29:31 UTC 2016

hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE
SYSTEM.CATALOG
SYSTEM.FUNCTION
SYSTEM.SEQUENCE
SYSTEM.STATS
ambarismoketest
ns:contact
ns:counters
ns:counters-backup
ns:lists
ns:logins
ns:modelLogs
ns:models
ns:reportLogs
ns:users
```

#### Questions

Does this sound like a correct conclusion? If so what are my options in terms of Phoenix?

- upgrade it within HW 2.3 (assuming this is not an option)?
- work around it somehow?
- Move Phoenix tables manually out of default NS into our applications? How?

#### References

- [HBase namespaces surfaced in phoenix](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-1311)
- [Support HBase non-default Namespace](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-1966)
- [Phoenix Schema should mapping to HBase Namespace](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-2721)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade Phoenix within HDP 2.3 by replacing the correct jar files in `/usr/hdp/......phoenix